# How to specify types not allowed in a .NET Generics constraint?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints

Is it possible to specify a constraint on a generic class that  disallows certain types?  I don't know if it is possible and if it is, I am not sure what the syntax would be.  Something like:

```
public class Blah<T> where : !string {
}
```

I can't seem to find any notation that would allow such a constraint.

Comment: don't think that this is possible - but why would you need something like this?

Comment: What is the desired behavior when someone tries to pass in a type that is not supported?

Comment: I actually was trying to exclude the string type, but it turns out that using where T : struct works for what I am trying to do since my class won't work for complex types anyways.

Comment: Out of interest, I'm trying to come up with a reason why this behavior is wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest you can get is a run-time constraint.

**Edit**: Originally I put the run-time check in the constructor call. That's actually not optimal, as it incurs overhead on every instantiation; I believe it would be much more sensible to put the check in the *static* constructor, which will be invoked once per type used as the `T` parameter for your `Blah<T>` type:

```
public class Blah<T> {
    static Blah() {
        // This code will only run ONCE per T, rather than every time
        // you call new Blah<T>() even for valid non-string type Ts
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The 'string' type argument is not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously not ideal, but if you put this constraint in place *and* document the fact that `string` is not a supported type argument (e.g., via XML comments), you should get somewhere *near* the effectiveness of a compile-time constraint.

Comment: typically I put constrains not expressible in C# into the class constructor.

Comment: To include type that can be resolved as string:  if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) throw new NotSupportedException

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't directly specify "negated" type constraints.

Comment: Is there an indirect method, other that something like Asserting that the typeof(T) is not something?

Comment: @SirPentor Not as part of the type constraint, though you could do something like that in code.

Answer (score 2):

Constraints can only be positive constraints, as outlined in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

The only thing you can do is specify what types *can* be put into the generic type, but you cannot specify what *can't* be put into them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the allowed constraints ([more detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx))

- where T: struct
- where T : class
- where T : new()
- where T : [base class name]
- where T : [interface name]
- where T : U (The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U)