# Generic parameters: ensure different types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class with two generic parameters. I want to restrict the second generic parameter to be a different type than the first one. Is there a way to make such a restriction at compile time? Checking the types at runtime is not very useful.

```
public class Test<A, B>
    where B : not_typeof(A)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is a slightly different scenario, but ultimately it is the same answer as the one @Sam links to

Comment: Do you have other constraints? Because when you have `where A : IUtensil`, `where B : IVehicle`, why do you care if a user has a `Test<Forklift, Forklift>`? It should work... Can you please add some more details?

Comment: You can't write a constraint like that, but of course you could put on other constraints which will guarantee that the types can't be the same, for example if `A` must derive from class `Animal` and `B` must derive from class `Bicycle`, and if neither of these two classes derives from the other, then you will know that `A` and `B` can't be the same type, like @Kobi hints at. Similarly if one has the `struct` constraint (non-nullable value type) and the other has the `class` constraint (reference type).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately I cannot restrict the parameters any further. The generic class should work with any type given. The only restriction I want is that `typeof(A) != typeof(B)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is at run-time.

I adapted the answer from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096375/how-to-specify-types-not-allowed-in-a-net-generics-constraint) I posted in the comments.

```
public class Test<A, B> {

    static Test() {
        if (typeof(B) == typeof(A)) {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Argument B is not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the solution I am currently working with. It works but it is nasty because you only see your error at run-time. I was looking for a solution working at compile-time. However I'll mark your post as answer because it seems there is (currently) no way to make such a restriction at compile-time.